# Vuejs safely api keys

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, vue.js, nuxtjs

I may still be a bit confused about the concept. But. In this scenario I have a contact form, which on send, is calling my own laravel backend api that will process the send email functionality for me.

I would like to secure it with an api key, but I don't want my api key to be exposed anywhere in the frontend. My Vue/Nuxt app is running served on the server.

So Env variables should be the answer - I guess. Though, If I do it like this:

```
this.$axios.$post('http://localhost/someMailFunc?apk=' + process.env.API_KEY, {
                    name: name,
                    subject: subject,
                    email: email,
                    message: message,
                }).then(response => {
                    // somecomplete
                }).catch(e => {
                    // somecatch
                })
```

Surely, in the code it's hidden, but inspect it in frontend, everywhere visible is the api key.

[image]
[image]

What would be the recommended way of securing with a key, if a key is even the solution today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that in this use case (a contact form) an API KEY is not the way to secure your api / contact form.

In a contact form, What do you need to secure?

- Submit of robots => **Solution**: Captcha (ex: Google Captcha)
- Submit repeatedly by evil people => **Solution**: Implement in your API a validation feature to prevent this verifying the agent and ip source.
- Submit by http request directly (whitout use your web form) => **Solution**: Implement domain constraints in your API (Allow only submits from your web domain)
- Man in the middle like evil proxy (theft and data manipulation) => **Solution** Implement HTTPS in your API

If your API needs an APIKEY, and this API is requested by a browser, your APIKEY will always be visible by dev tools.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your answer. I needed some kind of validation, due to the fact that I use my hosts smtp server. If they record any spamming process, they have the rights to close it: reason why I was going for a simple api secure solution in the first place. So your ideas definitely puts my head in the right direction, I think your right that I should do some of your suggested methods instead of a simple api key solution. :-)